# Yii Framework: Error when using a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array, yii

I'm having some problems getting this to work, I am sure there's an easy explanation, but I am not able to connect the dots at the moment.

I'm using Yii Framework 1.1.13 with the Twitter Bootstrap.

My controller looks like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $posts = array(
        'total' => 5,
        'items' => array(
            array(      
                'id' => 1,
                'header' => 'Praesent arcu nisi',
                'body' => 'Lacinia a dolor at, tempus suscipit diam.Lacinia a dolor at, tempus suscipit diam.Lacinia a dolor at, tempus suscipit diam.Lacinia a dolor at, tempus suscipit diam.Lacinia a dolor at, tempus suscipit diam.',
                'img' => '',
                'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
                'category' => 'Test',
                'company' => 'Example',
                'company_bkg' => '',
                'rating' => 8,
                'comments_total' => 2,
                'comments_items' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'name' => 'Anonymous',
                        'timestamp' => date('d.m.Y H:i'),
                        'text' => 'Kommentar 1.',
                        'rating' => 145,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 2,
                        'name' => 'Example',
                        'timestamp' => date('d.m.Y H:i'),
                        'text' => 'Kommentar 2.',
                        'rating' => -29,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(      
                'id' => 2,
                'header' => 'Lacinia a dolor at',
                'body' => 'Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi.',
                'img' => '',
                'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
                'category' => 'Test',
                'company' => 'Example',
                'company_bkg' => '',
                'rating' => 0,
                'comments_total' => 0,
                'comments_items' => array(
                    array(

                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(      
                'id' => 3,
                'header' => 'Lacinia a dolor at',
                'body' => 'Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi.',
                'img' => '',
                'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
                'category' => 'Test',
                'company' => 'Example',
                'company_bkg' => '',
                'rating' => -8,
                'comments_total' => 1,
                'comments_items' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'name' => 'Anonymous',
                        'timestamp' => date('d.m.Y H:i'),
                        'text' => 'Kommentar 1.',
                        'rating' => 9,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    $this->render('index',array('posts'=>$posts));
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $posts array */
/* @var $comment array */

...
foreach($posts['items'] as $post) {
...
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        $comment = $post['comments_items'][$i];
        var_dump($comment);

...
```

Which shows the following `var_dump`:

```
array (size=5)
  'id' => int 1
  'name' => string 'Anonymous' (length=9)
  'timestamp' => string '29.06.2013 15:57' (length=16)
  'text' => string 'Kommentar 1.' (length=12)
  'rating' => int 145
```

But when I do a `$comment['rating']`, it comes back with an error:

```
Undefined index: rating
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the second array like this:

```
        array(      
            'id' => 2,
            'header' => 'Lacinia a dolor at',
            'body' => 'Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi.',
            'img' => '',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'category' => 'Test',
            'company' => 'Example',
            'company_bkg' => '',
            'rating' => 0,
            'comments_total' => 0,
            'comments_items' => array(
                array(

                ),
            ),
        ),
```

There is no `rating` entry in the `comments_items`, that's why you getting the error.

Try adding the `rating` element too:

```
        array(      
            'id' => 2,
            'header' => 'Lacinia a dolor at',
            'body' => 'Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi. Praesent arcu nisi.',
            'img' => '',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'category' => 'Test',
            'company' => 'Example',
            'company_bkg' => '',
            'rating' => 0,
            'comments_total' => 0,
            'comments_items' => array(
                array(
                    'rating' => 1
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of your variable is $posts, not $post.

Look the name in this line:

```
$this->render('index',array('posts'=>$posts));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this was because I forgot to add a line of code to the view shown here. `foreach($posts['items'] as $post) {` has been edited into the code sample above.

Comment: Is it suposed that $length variable within for stament is comments_total key?